# Django simple button

Tags: python, django

I have big DetailView page, where i need to place a simple button for some actions. My button sends POST:
 "POST /temp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 60"    (Pycharm IDE log)
and it should print "Works!" or "Didnt works" in logs too, but noting hapends, help plz!

template:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Button" name="mybtn">
</form>
```

views.py:

```
class MyView(DetailView):
    model = Mymodel
    template_name = 'mypage_detail.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def mymethod(request):
        print ('Dont work :( ')    
        if(request.POST.get('mybtn')):
            print ('Works!')
        return render_to_response('App/yourtemplate.html')
```

models.py:

```
class Members(models.Model):            #ManyToMany
    uni = models.ForeignKey(Universe)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    ...
```

It returns:

But why it didnt prints anything?

Comment: You don't seem to be calling mymethod at all. How are you expecting it to be called?

Comment: Thanks) Really missed it. Im novice, can you plz tell me in where it should be called? Or in which part of docs i can find it. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean or what you're trying to do. You have defined a method called `mymethod`. Why have you done that? What are you expecting to do with that method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering where do you expect it to be printed, If you wanna see "works", you gotta pass it as a response something like this :

```
def mymethod(request):
    result = 'doesnt work'
    if(request.POST.get('mybtn')):
        result = 'works!'
    return HttpResponse(result, mimetype="application/json")
```

This way you can check the value of result which is the response, you can do it using firebug

Comment: you have to include this at the top of your view file: from django.http import HttpResponse